# Report Info on Home Page

Tags: reporting

I have a report that I need to display either on the Lightning home page or as a list view. However, the report is an Orders with Order Products report (two objects). This rules out List view (I believe).

I am able to get the chart of the report to display but the information is fairly useless as a chart.

Any ideas? At this point I'm thinking I will have to get the report to email to Users instead of being easily visible within Salesforce

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect users to report pages by creating a custom lightning component to display links to reports.

Comment: Thanks Aman. I was hoping to give them visibility to the 5 most recent records (for example) without having to re-direct them.